#  Not able to use the constant defined in Service class which is in different package

Tags: android

I am implementing "Bound Services" using messenger.
As given in "http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html", if I try accessing service.class[service is the name of the class] or service.constant in Message.obtain or bindService in my activity class, it is not recognizing service class name as a class.

Service class is in different package and the activity class is in different package.

Can anyone please help in fixing this error.
Do I have to add jar file of service in build path of activity??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your service class declared as public?

Otherwise, can you give more context? How exactly do you call the service class or service constant?

Comment: Hi, Yes Service class is public and constant data members too.  public class SensorDataCollector extends Service                 public static final int MSG_SURVEY_COMPLETED = 1; In activity I am using like SensorDataCollector.MSG_SURVEY_COMPLETED. But both are in different packages.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.
Do you use both classes in the same project (e.g. eclipse project)? Did you import the Service class inside your Activity?